# Math Shock in graduate program

Tags: education, learning

People call it Culture shock but I call it Math Shock... let me explain my Problem... First I am graduate student in a  good university in USA ( I get scholarship from my country). Before I lived in third world country and I finished my undergraduate with no one of my instructor who thought me have Ph.D  in other word they are all have only master ( education system is bad and the country was in war before ) and now I am in the second semester of my first year graduate program, in first course I get A in all class ( it was not difficult ). but my problem is not get A, I just want understand how its work?  I think I have problem to integrate with this new system.I fell the other student ( American Students ) have better background in math than me and this disappointed me, In many occasion I saw they get right answer with less effort while it took more time  for me . I do not have problem with hard working.I will be happy to share this question and get answer from other people in this forum.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: the afraid of losing scholarship and level of 1st world isn't enough to be motivated to work without being compared yourself versus other students?

Comment: maybe the OP is not adequately prepared to study graduate level math. Most students can be very good at undergraduate math, but few are good at graduate level. It doesn't have to do with 1st or 3rd world.

Comment: My question is clear @IgorRivin... " how could I pass all these struggle ? background and problem solving skills . hope this make more sense.

Comment: @janmarqz I am not afraid of losing the scholarship because I do not have problem to finish the requirement , I just want to be better.

Comment: @NowOrNever Thanks for your comment.but when I mention third world i do not mention all detail... let me give you one small detail... we was 40 student  and we have only one textbook for all of us. so there was lack of material and instructor also.

Comment: If there are deficiencies in your background, you will have to work harder than people with more background knowledge. Presumably you are prepared to do that. After a while you may be ahead.

Comment: Some people are better/faster thinkers than others, when it comes to maths. Even the ones that do things seemingly without much effort, have to work hard. Most people have difficulties at some point. Unfortunately, hard work in graduate school is sometimes not enough. Some things in maths take time to get used to and learning vast amounts in a short time can be very difficult in my experience (emotionally too when one is struggling with the 'understanding'),. It is a good question to ask. I hope you get an answer that helps.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas ... this is good suggestion and I will take it in consideration.

Comment: @NowOrNever That makes not sense in the thinnest of the ways. Anyone that have done well at the most elementary of all mathematics, plus work hard, and have the will to work, has all it takes to deal with all the mathematics in the world. The only thing needed to master it is to train it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks ..already I work on the background and I see the different...

Comment: @henry 1) Mathematics is vast and you will not master it all. 2) Take those parts of it in which you feel comfortable and work close to it, pushing out to what you haven't done but keeping close to your area of comfort. (This helps preserve confidence) 3) Many graduate students can seem very knowledgeable but sometimes it is only knowing the names of things. Lots of words and definitions. Modern mathematics has a cancer of terminology. Make sure you get strong on strategy and techniques, tricks. Those are more important in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @Karene ... I see your comment very helpful and positive.thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you had a disadvantage at your home country, if you are in graduate school at USA, it means you passed many filters (scholarship, admission exams, undergraduate grades, peer competition).

Definitely you will struggle more in the beginning, but you have what you need to succeed.  It will take more effort and will.

Just remember where you were a few years ago and how you dreamed to be where you are.  Now you are there and perhaps you just need to believe you are there.  You need to feel you deserve it, go for it.

It will be hard, but eventually it will get easier and you will enjoy it.

Congrats, wish you success.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and your kind word. Hope I could do best so I will be useful when I go back.

Comment: @henry, you are already getting straight A's, that is all you need to do for now.  Have you tried to explore other things other than school? You are a work in progress.  Focus more in the present, I guess by the way you describe you work, you will do fine in the future. Just balance your hard work with some recreation.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, particularly in maths, feeling that you are a slow learner can be a good thing.

Some people demand of themselves that they attain a much deeper degree of mastery of a subject, than others do.  While another person may be satisfied that they can apply the methods taught to them, others are only satisfied when they can apply the methods as taught, visualise how the methods work, relate them to all surrounding things, fully understand the boundaries in which those methods apply, explore all avenues and have a clear picture of the full gamut of innovative and unexpected ways they might also be used.

These people have to work much harder to be satisfied with their understanding, and they may feel they are finding it more difficult than others to learn.  In reality, they are simply setting the bar higher for themselves.

The classic example is Einstein who was famously slow to learn maths.  But it turned out that his mastery of what he learnt was simply deeper.